# Updating a MySQL via selected position

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a table based on the input provided by a user. There are ten fields which a user can choose to input information into. The table I am trying to input too has a following structure.

```
leagueTrackID | leagueID | trackID

   1                1          1

   2               1          2

   3               1          12

   ...

   15              1          4
```

I need the code to update the fields where a new track has been added via looping though each inputted track and place it in a new field which has the matching criteria. The criteria which it needs to be match too is the leagueID. How can this be achieved without overwriting the same column row?

The code below is what I have so far but I have an error with trying to assign the php track variables to either a php array or php list.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(leagueID) AS totalTracks , min(leagueTrackID) AS minLeagueID , max(leagueTrackID) AS maxLeagueID , leagueID , trackID
              FROM leagueTracks
              WHERE leagueID = '$vaildLeagueID'");

$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );

// get posted track id and assign them to the php track varaibles
if ( $_POST['track1'] == '' )  {     $track1 = $info['track1']; } else {    $track1 = $_POST['track1'];  }
if ( $_POST['track2'] == '' )  {     $track2 = $info['track2']; } else {    $track2 = $_POST['track2'];  }
if ( $_POST['track3'] == '' )  {     $track3 = $info['track3']; } else {    $track3 = $_POST['track3'];  }
if ( $_POST['track4'] == '' )  {     $track4 = $info['track4']; } else {    $track4 = $_POST['track4'];  }
if ( $_POST['track5'] == '' )  {     $track5 = $info['track5']; } else {    $track5 = $_POST['track5'];  }
if ( $_POST['track6'] == '' )  {     $track6 = $info['track6']; } else {    $track6 = $_POST['track6'];  }
if ( $_POST['track7'] == '' )  {     $track7 = $info['track7']; } else {    $track7 = $_POST['track7'];  }
if ( $_POST['track8'] == '' )  {     $track8 = $info['track8']; } else {    $track8 = $_POST['track8'];  }
if ( $_POST['track9'] == '' )  {     $track9 = $info['track9']; } else {    $track9 = $_POST['track9'];  }
if ( $_POST['track10'] == '' ) {     $track10 = $info['track10']; } else {  $track10 = $_POST['track10'];  }


// Assign tracks selected to an array
$tracksArray = array($track1 , '$track2' , '$track3', '$track4', '$track5' , '$track6' ,'$track7', '$track8' , '$track9' , '$tack10');

// Counter
$trackNumber = '1';

// Get the lowest leagueTrackID based on the leagueID being updated
$min = $info['minleagueID']; 

// Get the highest leagueTrackID based on the leagueID being updated
$max = $info['maxLeagueID'];

      while($min != $max) {

    $updateLeagueTracks = mysql_query ("UPDATE userLeague SET trackID = $trackArray['$tracknumber'] WHERE leagueID = '$vaildLeagueID'");

    $addTracks = mysql_query($updateLeagueTracks);

    $trackNumber++;
    $min++;

} // closes the for loop
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: @Kermit you are one of the brave men fighting the deprecation cause, I have gave up on this battle, if you want `mysql_` go crazy with it. By now everyone should know ;)

Comment: Are there any good resources available to read up on migrating the code?

Comment: @meda It's like Ebola. Patients were told not to go outside and yet they went outside.